# Is it possible to run Mac OS X 10.5 as a virtual machine on my Mac OS X 10.6 install?

Tags: virtualization

I've tried using VirtualBox, but the only option it gives me is Mac OS X Server. When I try to boot using my 10.4 disk, I get some vague message about startup.nsh, then a `Shell>` prompt, so I assume it won't work. Does Parallels or VMWare Fusion support running 10.5 on 10.6 as a VM?

### Update:

Turns out the disk was damaged. If VirtualBox cannot find a valid disc, it will start the EFI utility. After using a new disc that is verified as working, I found that it worked with the "Mac OS X Server" option in the latest VirtualBox.

Comment: Hmm, maybe this will do it? http://www.sysprobs.com/install-mac-os-1055-leopard-virtualbox-314-installation-dvd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VritualBox supports OS X guests **inofficially** and only on OS X hosts. But the EULA states:

> A. Single Use License. Subject to the
>   terms and conditions of this License,
>   unless you have purchased a Family
>   Pack or Upgrade license for the Apple
>   Software, **you are granted a limited
>   non-exclusive license to install, use
>   and run one (1) copy of the Apple
>   Software on a single Apple-branded
>   computer at a time**. You agree not to
>   install, use or run the Apple Software
>   on any non-Apple-branded computer, or
>   to enable others to do so. This
>   License does not allow the Apple
>   Software to exist on more than one
>   computer at a time, and you may not
>   make the Apple Software available over
>   a network where it could be used by
>   multiple computers at the same time.

I tested it: Install Virtualbox, insert your disc and create a new VM - works like a charm!

**[edit]** i changed my answer do reflect the actual EULA terms (which still don't apply in some countries like Germany)

**[edit2]**
Here are some screenshots:

The first one shows Snow Leopard (MacBook Installation DVD) in VirtualBox 3.2-BETA1. The second one shows the same virtual machine (created in BETA1) running under 3.2.8 and booting from a Leopard Upgrade DVD.

Creating an OS X Server VM (without altering any other settings!) worked fine for me, too!
I didn't complete the install, though. My 10.5 Insallation DVD requires 10.4 to be installed and i didn't have enough time to install 10.6 either.

[image: Booting Snow Leopard (MacBook Mid 2010 Install Disc, Virtualbox 3.2-BETA1)]
[image: Booting Leopard (Leopard Upgrade DVD), Virtualbox 3.2.whateverthecurrentversionis]

Comment: Which VM type did you choose? I chose Mac OS X Server and had no success. Is your disk for the desktop or server version?

Comment: By the way, if I choose "Mac OS X Server" and disable the EFI option, then insert my Mac OS X 10.5 disk (not server), it reads the disk for a second, then I see "FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted."

Comment: Hm: back then i installed Snow Leopard in VirtualBox 3.2 because of this article:  http://bit.ly/9kkzvm Sadly the link in the article is no longer valid! Maybe you should try the OSW edition (but i'm sure i used the "normal" version)

Comment: Here's a link to the beta, try it out: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/3.2.0_BETA1/ I don't know why they removed the feature. I have to look at this when i got more time.

Comment: Question: Is your 10.5 Disk for a PPC- or Intel-Mac?

Comment: The DVD is for Intel Mac - I also tried using the Snow Leopard disk (which works fine for my Intel Mac mini). I will try VirtualBox beta tonight.

Comment: BTW - Second image link is broken.

Comment: Also, did you have the option for "Mac OS X" (desktop) as well as "Mac OS X Server"? I guess I'll find out tonight :)

Comment: BETA 1 has an option for "Mac OS X [with and w/o(64 Bit)]". The current version 3.2.8 only offers "Mac OS X Server [with and w/o(64 Bit)]". But i started the Leopard installer on 3.2.8 (i.e. in a "Server"-VM). About the image: it shows up for me... URL: http://i.imgur.com/hvPIj.png - 1st Image: http://i.imgur.com/Q3ctv.png

Comment: With 3.2.8 did you need to disable the EFI option?

Comment: no. I did the following: Create new Machine. Type: OS X Server (no 64 Bit). Click "next" until the setup is finished. Then start it. The machine will ask for a bootable disk, since it's the first start of the newly created machine. "insert" the OS X Disk Image/DVD. Boot and install. Remember to format the disk using the installer's Disk Utility before installing!

Comment: What's your Host's OS? I'm running Snow Leopard 10.6.4

Comment: My host is 10.6.4 also (on Mac mini 32-bit). Using the Snow Leopard DVD with BETA1 I've finally managed to get to the Welcome screen - hurrah! The text displayed before that was a little scary, something about a BUG (I guess an assertation failed). However, I haven't tried to fully install yet so I might be speaking too soon. Also, I had to change the LAN mode from NAT to Bridged (because of some VirtualBox network error code). I have also tried using the Macbook 10.5 CDs but this brings me to the EFI shell; I guess the disk isn't supported?

Comment: Correction, not a CD, it's a DVD "hardware bundle" -- "not to be sold separately".

Comment: It depends: What kind of MacBook do you have? Maybe it's a 64 Bit MacBook? I.e. 64 Bit installation DVDs. I don't know if you can run a 64 Bit guest on a 32 host (i have doubts!)

Comment: About the text you saw before the welcome screen: That's normal. I had a lot of output, too (see new screen shot)

Comment: sorry, uploading fails. but the text is normal.

Answer (score 1):

[VMware Fusion](http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-10958), [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/system-requirements/), & [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes) only officially support Mac OS X Server 10.5 and 10.6. The problem is is that the Mac OS X [EULA](http://www.apple.com/legal/sla/) states that Mac OS X may not be virtualized.

Comment: Why the downvote. As far as I can tell, the answer is correct.